# How to generate all possible NXK matrices where each row is a onehot vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider a NxK array (its for a segmentation scenario). 
Exactly one element in each row should be a '1'. All others should be '0'. This is for specific dot multiplication purposes.

What I need is to have a loop structure (probably recursive since neither N or K are fixed values) where all possible combinations are created.

Thus for a 3x2 matrix, we have `([1,0],[1,0],[1,0])` changed to `([1,0],[1,0],[0,1])` and then `([1,0],[0,1],[1,0])` followed by `([1,0],[0,1],[0,1])` and then `([0,1],[1,0],[1,0])` and `([0,1],[1,0],[0,1])` and `([0,1],[0,1],[1,0])` and finally `([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])`.

It's not difficult if N is a small no and for do loops are fine. But once it becomes large, I just have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Dear Professor, could you format your code part to make it a bit more readable?

Comment: format your code... atleast 4 spaces before every line

Comment: So have u tried anything?

Comment: Sorry. New to asking questions :)

Comment: Welcome @Professor. When asking questions: Don't repeat yourself. Don't include thanks and other non-essentials. Reread your post and check your spelling. Spent a minute on learning how to format "code" (inline and as block), it makes your post more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
from itertools import permutations,product
columns = 2
rows = 3
one_hot = [0]*(columns-1) +[1] # we are going to get all permutation of this one hot list
for i in product(set(permutations(one_hot,columns)),repeat=rows):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
((0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0))
((0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1))
((0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0))
((1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 1))
((1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
((1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))
((1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I have no idea how, but I wil figure it out :)

Comment: Ok, ran into a slight problem. If K =2 as is the case above, then there is no problem. However, if K>2 there are two or more zeros and each is taken as a separate element and the same combination is repeated (since the two zeros are distinct). Thus the number of permutations blows up. I'm working on it, but if I'd appreciate any help. Thanks for introducing me to itertools :)

Comment: I have fixed that by adding a set operation . Hope this fixes your issue.